# Managing /etc/rsnaphost file for mutliple servers

Tags: rsnapshot

I'm looking into the best way to manage the /etc/rsnapshot file which tells rsnapshot what to backup. I have about a hundred servers. While I could modify the /etc/rsnapshot file manually, I'm sure someone has invented this wheel before. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your existing configuration management system?

Comment: I'm using Rex to manage my servers if that's what you mean. I think I have found a solution that works for me which is easy to automate. Basically, I give each server its own backup directory on the backup server along with its own rsnapshot.conf file. The rsnapshot.conf can start as a simple template file and changed to contain the remote server's information. What's nice is I can easily add in custom configurations for each server if I want or need to. I use the include_conf directive which I use in the custom config file for each server to include the master config located at /etc/rsnaphot.

Answer (score 0):

[`Rocknroll`](https://github.com/JacquelinCharbonnel/rocknroll.git) is an lowtech alternative to rsnapshot, that don't need a file of parameters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/543598)